# Remotely connecting to Hyper-V machine from VM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm new to the concept of Hyper-V and how it works, so I'm not sure if this is a good question.

I have a server that contains the Hyper-V, and from the Hyper-V I connect to a VM (VM1). The VM1 contains Orchestrator that will be used to automate some jobs related to the machines in the Hyper-V sever. So I need to run some PowerShell commands, in VM1, to check the Snapshots of all the machines in the Hyper-V server.
I already installed the Hyper-V PowerShell module in VM1.
My question is, in order to get information about the machines in Hyper-V through VM1:

- Do I need to install the Hyper-V Management Tools in VM1 and make a connection to the main Hyper-V server in order to get information about the other VMs in Hyper-V?
- Can I do this by using a remote PowerShell session and then run the commands that I need against the Hyper-V server, remotely. Can I do this when VM1 is accessible through Hyper-V?

It's a bit difficult to explain, like I said I'm new to this topic. But I'm available to answer any question if my explanation was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From VM1, you should be able to connect to the Hyper-V host using `-computername` and `-name` to reference the name of the VM:

```
$Host = "HypervHostServer"
$VM = "virtualmachine1"
Get-VM -ComputerName $Host -Name $VM
```

To see all virtual machines:

```
$Host = "HypervHostServer"
Get-VM -ComputerName $Host
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And the user needs specific permissions to do this? Maybe Admin permissions?

Comment: On each Hyper-V server, there is a local group called "Hyper-V Administrators"